# Find maximum value in list of lists according to filter in R

Tags: r, list

I want to compare a certain value in a list of lists in R. This is a shortened example.

```
list1=rbind(element, data.frame(name=c("city", "town", "village"),size=c(5,3,8),height=c(13, 20,19)))
           
list2=rbind(element, data.frame(name=c("city", "town", "village"),size=c(4,6,3), height=c(11, 22,14)))

list3=rbind(element, data.frame(name=c("city", "town", "village"),size=c(7,5,9), height=c(23, 16,11)))

list=list(list1, list2, list3)
```

I want to compare all lists according to name= "village" and find the minimum, median and maximum value for "size". Additionally I want the number of the lists with the minimum, median and maximum value. Actually there are many lists. I tried the folowing. It works, but probably there is an easier way. Especially, to find the number of the list.

```
dt_list <- map(list, as.data.table)
dt <- rbindlist(dt_list, fill = TRUE, idcol = T)
village_list=dt%>% filter(name=="village")

village_size<- village_list[,3]
summary (village_size)
```

Comment: When I tried to create the list I got an error message `Error in rbind(element, data.frame(name = c("city", "town", "village"),  : 
  object 'element' not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the data frames into a single one and summarise to get the stats you're looking for:

```
library(dplyr)

list %>%
  bind_rows(.id="id") %>%
  filter(name == 'village') %>%
  summarise(min(size), max(size), median(size), id[which.min(size)], id[which.max(size)], id[which.min(abs(size - median(size)))])
```